# How can I convert an Android game to HTML5?

Tags: android, html5

How can I convert an Android game to HTML 5?

Comment: Are you using your own engine or third party game engine? Please specify about that.

Comment: The answer below is right. You have to use f.e. meteor, ionic, cordova etc.

Comment: To whoever flagged this question, please stop, and read [this post](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/please-flag-responsibly). This question is not VLQ.

Answer (score 3):

There are some frameworks (like PhoneGap) which can build an application for multiple build targets. But only if you developed the application from scratch with that framework.

When it is a native Android application, then you can't just push a button and turn it into JavaScript. You will have to rewrite it from scratch. But porting an application from one programming language to another is usually less work than it took to develop it initially. You already solved all the problems conceptually. You just need to translate your solutions to a different language.